# Override Jackson implicit deserializion for primitive types

Tags: json, jackson, primitive-types, json-deserialization

Is there a way to configure Jackson parser to be very strict when deserialize "primitive" type values? For example, if property is boolean, Jackson will successfully map all JSON values: true, "true", "True", 1, 123, -123.
In other words, how to instruct Jackson to accept only *true*?
Similar, for integer type, values 5, 5.21, "5" will be successfully mapped. But what if only *5* is acceptable as integer?
Beside registering custom deserializers for (all?) primitive types, is there better way to achieve more "strict" mapping?
Thanks...